# What is the proper PInvoke signature for a function that takes var args?

Tags: .net, interop, pinvoke

There is a native function:

```
int sqlite3_config(int, ...);
```

I would like to PInvoke to this function. Currently, I have this declaration:

```
[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_config")]
public static extern Result Config (ConfigOption option);
```

(Result and ConfigOption are enums of the form `enum Result : int { ... }`.)

I am actually only interested in the single parameter version of this function and don't need the other args. Is this correct?

I am also curious as to how you would declare the two argument form (perhaps it would take 2 IntPtrs?).

Comment: I wonder if the title **What is the proper PInvoke signature for a variadic function?** would be more Google friendly.

Comment: I've been programming C my entire career and I still can't remember the word **variadic** :-)

Comment: Those computer scientists and their weird names! Apparently, arity means **the number of arguments that a function can take**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the __arglist keyword (which is undocumented), Bart# had a [nice blog about it.](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/28/4473.aspx)

**Example**

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int wsprintf([Out] StringBuilder lpOut, string lpFmt, __arglist);

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var sb  = new StringBuilder();
        wsprintf(sb, "%s %s %s", __arglist("1", "2", "3"));
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
    }       
}
```

The is no standard way of pinvoking vararg methods, most solutions will wrap it in several methods e.g.

```
[DllImport("MyDll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern var MyVarArgMethods1(String fmt, 
    String arg1);

[DllImport("MyDll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern var MyVarArgMethods2(String fmt, 
    String arg1, String arg2);
```

Comment: probably miss the deadline for the ECMA submission and now MS will not commit to that keyword until its part of the sepc.

Comment: That makes sense. I also can't help but wonder why they use `__arglist` rather than `arglist`.

Comment: I updated wsprintf on pinvoke.net to use __arglist
http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/wsprintf.html

Comment: I have to remember to do that when I find errors. Gotta give back to the community somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I don't normally do this but I figured it couldn't hurt.