# P/Invoking a function with a variadic signature

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pinvoke, variadic

I have a C#.NET 2.0 CF application that imports a function from a native DLL with the following signature:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) void DLL_Foo( int count, ... );
```

My C# application P/Invokes that function as follows:

```
public sealed class MyObject
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        NativeMethods.DLL_Foo(2, __arglist("a","b")); 
    }

    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("My.dll")]
        internal static extern void DLL_Foo(int count, __arglist);
    }
}
```

But, when I invoke `MyObject.Foo`, I get a `System.MissingMethodException`.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Thanks,
PaulH

---

**Edit:** If I change the import definition to:

```
internal static extern void DLL_Foo(int count, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string a, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string b);
```

then, call:

```
NativeMethods.DLL_Foo(2, "a", "b");
```

It works with no problems, so it's something with my `__arglist` usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure (and I have never done it) if you can have `params` args in P/Invoke but you might give it a try.

```
internal static extern void DLL_Foo(int count, params string[] args);
```

Comment: That's very interesting. Once I step in to the `NativeMethods.DLL_Foo(2, new string[]{"a", "b"})` method, I go no further. The program stays running, but doesn't continue to the next line of code. I also tried this against `wsprintf()` from coredll.dll just to be sure it isn't the DLL being naughty. Same result.

Comment: Oops. I should have looked at the device screen. "A native exception has occurred in..." The code is 0x80000002, which I believe is a datatype misalignment.

Comment: @Paul I think you probably have to have a number of overloads with multiple strings and that should do the trick - though won't achieve what you wanted to.

Comment: It seems to work in the the non-compact-framework. http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/28/4473.aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124490/what-is-the-proper-pinvoke-signature-for-a-function-that-takes-var-args

Answer (score 0):

You should be using  `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` for your DllImport. The `CallingConvention.Cdecl` description states it.

```
using LPWORD = System.IntPtr;
using LPVOID = System.IntPtr;

[DllImport("foo.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern LPVOID extFunc(LPWORD lpdwMandatory,__arglist);
```

And then You can call **extFunc** function:

```
extFunc(lp1,__arglist( 0xFF,0x6A,0xAA));
```